# Add or override an item in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I would like to know how to find the array key from a multidimensional array.

I've got this:

```
$_SESSION['shop'] = array();
//Now I insert some values
$_SESSION['shop'][] = array("idproduct", "amount");
```

I would like to, if I insert a product to the array with the same idproduct, overwrite the "amount", instead of adding a new value to the main array.

I've tried doing a loop with `foreach` from `$_SESSION` and doing a `array_search`, but don't know if that's the best way, the only one...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that that is the structure you have? Your arry just holds keys, no information? How do you want to increase the amount?

Comment: Hi Andresch Serj, sorry, forgot to add [] when adding the values (only here, I got them in the code).
By just entering the array and changing the amount value would be fine.

Comment: You still do not have a structure that supports your desired feature. Try `$_SESSION['shop'][] = array('idproduct' => '<the product id>', 
'amount' => 0);`

Comment: the key from idproduct is 0, for amount is 1 if they aren't specified. As I only going to have thouse two I didn't see it necessary to specify them.

Comment: You only have those two? And you want to adjust the later of them if a duplicate entry for the first of them happens? At least to me that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fast way to access already existing entries in your shop array and it shouldn't be possible to have two entries with the same `idproduct` entry, you could just use the product id as a key in your array. Then use [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check if the entry is set:

Example given, assuming you have a product id stored in `$idProduct`:

```
if(array_key_exists($idProduct,$_SESSION['shop'])) {
  $_SESSION['shop'][$idProduct][amount]++;
}
else {
  $_SESSION['shop'][$idProduct] = array("idproduct" => $idProduct, "amount" => 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and effective! Good idea entering the idproduct as key. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a collection how they are usually built, an array of associative arrays or objects ([**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/EV09b)):

```
$products = array(
    array('idproduct' => 1, 'amount' => 5),
    array('idproduct' => 2, 'amount' => 10),
    array('idproduct' => 3, 'amount' => 11),
    array('idproduct' => 4, 'amount' => 5)
);
```

You can build a small function which merges an allready existing item or adds it if its not there:

```
function addOrOverride(&$arr, $newItem) {
    $filtered = array_filter($arr, function($item) use($newItem) {
        return $item['idproduct'] == $newItem['idproduct'];
    });

    if(count($filtered) > 0) {
        $key = key($filtered);
        $arr[$key] = array_merge($arr[$key], $newItem);
    } else {
        $arr[] = $newItem;
    }
}
```

And call it with your new or existing data:

```
addOrOverride($products, array('idproduct' => 4, 'amount' => 6));
```

Your `$products` array then looks like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> array(2) {["idproduct"]=> int(1) ["amount"]=> int(5)}
  [1]=> array(2) {["idproduct"]=> int(2) ["amount"]=> int(10)}
  [2]=> array(2) {["idproduct"]=> int(3) ["amount"]=> int(11)}
  [3]=> array(2) {["idproduct"]=> int(4) ["amount"]=> int(6)}
}
```

This by the way makes use of a php 5.3 anonymous function so consider the php version here.

Comment: Thanks for it. This could be very useful if I would need to replicate the situation in more pages from the web. I'll take for now the answer from above for the moment. Thanks!